# Как сделать фильтр, если связь между записью один ко многим?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица места и таблица особенностей места.
У места может быть несколько особенностей.
Нужно сделать выборку с WHERE где место соответствует нескольким особенностям.

[image: Таблица связи]

Comment: Выглядит как повод для join. Покажите DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM features
WHERE features_id IN ('feature_1', 'feature_2', ...)
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING count(distinct features_id) = <количество особенностей в списке IN>
```